# Replacing the Classloader of a Spring Boot Application (to produce a plugin system)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader

I'm writing a web application in Spring Boot, and I'd like it to support 'plug ins' (in my case, these are classes that implement a certain interface and provide additional functionality such as new REST API end points).

I have this working fine, and on start my application scans the class path for these interfaces and makes them available to the appropriate parts of my application (via a Service). However, I'd like to extend this so that I can:

1. Detect new plug ins that are dropped into a certain folder whilst the application is running, and make these available to the application
2. Detect plug ins that are removed whilst the application is running, and make these unavailable to the application
3. Detect changes to plug ins and reload them

What would be the best way to achieve that, given I've ruled out the use of OSGi? From the reading around I've done, it looks like I'll need to play around with the classloader, which is something I've not done before.

Should I be replacing the classloader used by Spring Boot with my own, or is there a way of extending it so that I can load and unload additional JARs at runtime? And how do I do that (whatever *that* may be)?

Comment: Why would you rule out OSGi? From what you've written, it's the exact tool for the job, and it's a mature, standardized technology.

Comment: At the time I decided it was too heavyweight for what I actually want to do, and now I've already got the majority of the code written I don't particularly want to go back and rewrite it all.

Comment: Well it's your decision of course, but the kind of plug-in framework you're talking about, with dynamic loading, unloading, and reloading of classes in a robust way isn't trivial. It's probably not terribly difficult to do "quick and dirty" but that may or may not be robust enough for your needs.

Comment: Also, what "majority of code" have you written? From the way I read the question, you don't know what code to write.

Comment: Everything is written and working to load plug ins from the classpath at the moment (and a number of plug ins have been developed). I'm now trying to extend what I've got so that the plug ins can be detected, loaded and unloaded dynamically at run time, rather than having to change the classpath and restart the app.